# Cookies not store over http. So I want run both server on same port to solve this problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, express, next.js

I have front end in nextjs and backend in express, nodejs. Both projects run on different ports.
Frontend run on 3000 and backend run on 8080. Now when I run project on local machine cookies store in front end works so fine. But when i host website on azure and use domain, request is over http and I have problem that frontend not store cookies over http.

I see some ways to solve this problem

## Using ssl cerficate

## Running both server on same port with the help of proxy.

Now I want to run both server on same port so that cookies easily stored on http request.
Can you give me idea how can I run both server on same port.

I have tried using ssl certificate but I am not able to set up properly.

Comment: Do you get any error in azure logs? if so could you please share them as well

Comment: I think this is related to your webserver configuration

Comment: You can't run two servers on the same port.  But cookies are not dependent upon the port (two servers on the same domain, but different ports can share cookies) so cookies should be fine if everything is configured properly.   If cookies are set with the `Secure` attribute, then those will only be sent to https servers.

Comment: But I recieve error of cross domain over http.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the following attributes with your cookies:

```
  Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>; SameSite=None; Secure
```

By doing this you are making sure that the SameSite policies of browsers are not interfering in your communication.